# Rails Migration for ID Column to Start at 1,000 and Autoincrement Up From There?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'd like the ID's of my Order model to start at 1000, and count up autoincrementally from there.

Can this be done via migration?

Comment: complete guess but did you try  create_table :whatever_table, :id => 1000 do |t|

Comment: What database are you using? e.g. mysql, postgresql, etc?

Comment: Currently using Sqlite3, will be migrating to postgres soon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your migration, after table has been created, update the sequence with something like this:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string  :name
  # other stuff
end

# for Postgres
execute "SELECT setval('products_id_seq', 1000)"

# and for mysql ...
execute "ALTER TABLE products AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000"
```

Comment: How to assign the product table id < 1000 in this way?

Answer (score 1):

In case if you just need to start the ID of a table from a custom number(lets say 1001).

And you are not sure about writing migration for the same, You can run the following in the `rails console`:

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT setval('table_name_id_seq', 1000)"

Tested worked well for me.
Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested and I am not sure what db you are using.

```
create_table(:order, :id => false) do |t|
   t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY', :default => 1000
```

or if you already have the table try this migration

```
def change
  execute "ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000"
end
```