# Postgres start table ID from 1000

Tags: sql, postgresql

Before you mark this a duplicate. I found this answer on another thread and having difficulties making it work.

From psql I see my table:

```
\d people
```

Table:

> Column        |                              Type                           |                                            Modifiers
>   ---------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   id                         |               integer                                     |       not null default
>   nextval('people_id_seq'::regclass)

Code I tried which seems to do nothing...

```
ALTER SEQUENCE people_id_seq RESTART 1000
```

**How do I make the primary key start from 1000?**

Comment: You can try `SELECT setval('people_id_seq', 999);`

Comment: try also if this can help [see this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076741/rails-migration-for-id-column-to-start-at-1-000-and-autoincrement-up-from-there

Comment: "in another thread". Link?

Comment: "seems to do nothing"? Well, what happens before/after? How do you determine what it does/doesn't do? Show some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following query would set the sequence value to 999. The next time the sequence is accessed, you would get 1000.

```
SELECT setval('people_id_seq', 999);
```

**Reference**:

[Sequence Manipulation Functions on PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you declaring your id like that ?

I mean, I would do the following :

create table people(
id serial,
constraint primaryKeyID primary key(id));

And now if you want to start your sequence from 1000, your alter query will work.

alter sequence people_id_seq restart 1000